# Для чего применяется значение атрибута rel="tag"?

Tags: html

И как актуально его применение на практике
(Прошу не присылать ссылки на HTMLbook и тд).
Мне не понятно описание этого значения как раз отсюда и из других похожих источников

Answer (score 0):

Тег - это тег, ярлык, ссылка на нечто к чему относится текущая страница

```
Итак, теги: 
  <a rel=tag href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">[ru-SO]</a>
  <a rel=tag href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html">[html]</a>
```